# How to share remix workspace from two or more computers?

Tags: solidity, remix

(sorry if its a basic question) As stated in question above, is it possible to share remix work on two or more computers?

Scenario: 1 is my laptop, another pc is at my office, third one is my VM. I want to share remix work on all these machines, that if I update any file from my laptop it should be updated wheren i open remix ide from office-pc or VM.

Thanks in advance please guide.

Answer (score 0):

First, it can't be done at the moment.

My advice is to install the development environment on each of your devices and use GitHub to manage your code.Of course, you can use GitHub only to store code and use Remix to execute it,But that would be a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an easy solution. Let me first understand your scenario. Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Scenario: You're using Remix relying on the files saved in your browser storage. You wish to have those files on another PC without having to download, share and upload them each time you move from PC1 to PC2.

Solution: Gist.

1. Open Settings in your Remix on PC1, add a Github token. You will be guided on how to create a Github token with Create Gist permission there itself.
2. In your Remix Files section, notice the Github icon, clicking on that will create a Gist on your github account, upload all your files to that gist, and share the URL with you. Keep that URL, it'll be used on PC2 to fetch all the files.
3. Now open Remix IDE on PC2. On the welcome screen, you'll see an option to import files from Gist, click on it.
4. Get the URL from PC1 to PC2, then paste it on the popup here. And it's done, all your files will be downloaded on PC2.
5. Once you've made your changes and want to syncronise the changes to be available on say PC1 or any other machine, you MUST update your gist. Simply right click on the files area and click on "Push changes to gist" option. It'll push all your changes to the same gist, and using the same URL you can again download it on any other PC, and so on..